# Install Split Apks Programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, installation, google-play, apk

I have an app which can be used to install other apps.
Currently I use this logic to install:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
context.startActivity(intent)
```

In the above code, `fileUri` points to the location of apk file and it works well. How can I install Split APKs using the same logic? not able to find any code refs regarding that.

JFYI: I also use PackageInstaller for installing but I use the above logic as a fallback. I know how to install Split APKs using PackageInstaller but not sure on how to install by using the above logic.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. I am currently installing using PackageInstaller but this is also required. If I find any solution, I will update here.

Comment: @DreamCoder can you plz tell how u r doing it using package installer? As much i know there is no else way. Except by Anti Split the Split into APK using any tool. I saw app named Anti Split you can try that too

Comment: @DiLDoSTWahag, I am talking about PackageInstaller class in Android - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller

Comment: @DreamCoder i know what you are talking about. Am asking can you plz share me the codes on how you are doing it exactly? Coz' this is also what am searching for... I'll be thankful